# Calling setDetached not working after upgrade to EF6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, breeze

I have this code :

```
 while (length > 0) {
            productArrival.productDetailsOptionValues()[length - 1].entityAspect.setDetached();
            length = length - 1;
```

But now it throws an error at the `setDetached`.
The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

This started happening after I upgraded to EF6 and latest breezeJs. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Just some more information. The table definition for the navigation property above is:

```
public class ProductDetailOptionValue
    {

        public int ProductDetailsId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProductDetailsId")]
        [InverseProperty("ProductDetailsOptionValues")]
        public ProductDetails ProductDetail { get; set; }

        public int OptionValueId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OptionValueId")]
        [InverseProperty("ProductDetailsOptionValues")]
        public OptionValue OptionValue { get; set; }
    }
```

the other parent entities are defined like:

```
public class ProductDetails
    {
        [Required]
        public virtual int ProductDetailsId { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        [InverseProperty("Details")]
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }


        [InverseProperty("ProductDetail")]
        public virtual ICollection<ProductDetailOptionValue> ProductDetailsOptionValues { get; set; }

    }
```

and:

```
public class OptionValue
    {
        [Required]
        public virtual int OptionValueId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual string Value { get; set; }

        public int ProductOptionsId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductOptionsId")]
        [InverseProperty("OptionValues")]
        public virtual ProductOptions Option { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("OptionValue")]
        public virtual ICollection<ProductDetailOptionValue> ProductDetailsOptionValues { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT 2:

I tried to debug a little bit inside Breezejs. It is crashing in this method:

```
function __arrayRemoveItem(array, predicateOrItem, shouldRemoveMultiple) {
  var predicate = __isFunction(predicateOrItem) ? predicateOrItem : undefined;
  var lastIx = array.length - 1;
  var removed = false;
  for (var i = lastIx; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (predicate ? predicate(array[i]) : (array[i] === predicateOrItem)) {
      array.splice(i, 1); // #####CRASHES HERE######
      removed = true;
      if (!shouldRemoveMultiple) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return removed;
}
```